# Transfer tracks between two or more playlists

Tags: soundcloud, drag-and-drop

Does SoundCloud have a page where I can manage my playlists using the drag and drop interface?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such support from SoundCloud.

To re-assign track into alt playlist you need to use again **+Add to playlist**.